# Different ways to ask Windows to write data to disk

Tags: windows, operating-system, hook, disk

Usually, when an application writes to one of it's files on disk, the file modified timestamp changes.

Sometimes, and in my case it is an application written in ProvideX (a Business Basic derivative i believe) doing the writing, the modified timestamp does not change after a write.  A program like MyTrigger will not pick up on the write operation either, but Sysinternals ProcessMonitor does log the disk activity.

It seems obvious that there are different ways to ask windows to perform write operations, and the request could then be hooked or logged in various different ways as well.

I need to be able to hook the write operations coming from the ProvideX application. Any pointers on the different ways windows writes to disk, and the type of hooks available for them would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not qualified to give a complete answer, hence the comment, but I know that you can write and append a file, at which point the modified date is changed, or you can create a temp file and rename it (or copy it) to the name you're monitoring, in which case it won't be updated until the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-mode process can write to the file either using WriteFile API function or using MMF, memory-mapped file API (CreateFileMapping/MapViewOfFile/Write to memory block). Maybe your application goes MMF way. MMF writes to files very differently from WriteFile API, but they both lead to the same end point - IRP sent to file system driver. File system filter driver (such as the one used by Sysinternals stuff) can track write requests on that IRP level. It is technically possible to distinguish between write operations initiated by MMF and WriteFile as different IRPs are sent (cached and non-cached writing is involved). It seems that directory change monitoring function in windows tracks only one IRP type, and this causes MyTrigger to miss the change.

Comment: thanks. i will have to google all those terms and then try them before i can tell if this is what i need, but it looks right!

Comment: [Memory Mapped File I/O May or May not Update the File Modified Timestamp](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/elyasse/archive/2010/04/18/memory-mapped-file-i-o-may-or-may-not-update-the-file-modified-timestamp.aspx) Not that this answers the question but it may be the cause of the problem.